# Physical installation of MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I install ASP.NET MVC, am I installing a different run-time, compiler, etc?  Or, is it just GACing some managed assemblies for the framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is installing `System.Web.Abstractions.dll`, `System.Web.Routing.dll` and `System.Web.Mvc.dll` assemblies into the GAC and depending on the type of install it could also install a VS project template.

Answer (score 1):

MVC uses the same runtime and same compiler.  It will add new project templates, page and controller templates to Visual Studio template folders. Also assemblies are added to the GAC.